# Errno 13: Permission denied. How to fix?

Tags: python, neural-network

Good evening.
I am having difficulty accessing one of the dataset folders. I have repeatedly reassigned folder owners and issued a full list of permissions. Including the files that are stored in them, but nothing helps. The error persists.
Could you suggest a solution to this problem?

The path to the dataset: D: \ keras-tutorial \ codes \ ... and then there are two folders with images of qr-codes (Bcodes and Ccodes). They store normal Qr codes and damaged ones (have graphic defects).

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from imutils import paths
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import keras
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
 
def obj():
    def obj_filter(obj):
        def populate_dict_with_module_objects(target_dict, modules, obj_filter):
            for module in modules:
                for name in dir(module):
                    obj = getattr(module, name)
                    if obj_filter(obj):
                        target_dict[name] = obj
 
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset of images")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to output trained model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--label-bin", required=True,
    help="path to output label binarizer")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", required=True,
    help="path to output accuracy/loss plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
 
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
 
def process_image(img_path):
    print(f"Processing image: {img_path}")
    img = Image.open(img_path)
 
    print (img.info)
 
    del img
 
images_dir = "D:\keras-tutorial\codes"
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    images_list = os.listdir(images_dir)
    print(images_list)
 
    for img_filename in images_list:
        img_path = os.path.join(images_dir, img_filename)
        process_image(img_path)
        
print("[INFO] loading images...")
data = []
labels = []
 
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)
 
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32)).flatten()
    data.append(image)
 
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)
 
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (data,
    labels, test_size=0.25, train_size=None, random_state=42)
 
lb = LabelBinarizer()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)
 
def create_model(lyrs=[8], act='linear', opt='Adam', dr=0.0):
    seed(42)
    tf.random.set_seed(42)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[0], input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation=act))
    for i in range(1, len(lyrs)):
        model.add(tf.keras.Dense(lyrs[i], activation=act))
        model.add(tf.keras.Dropout(dr))
        model.add(tf.keras.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.complete(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
 
    model = tf.keras.KerasClassifier(build_nf=create_model, verbose=0)
 
    batch_size = [16, 32, 64]
    epochs = [50, 100]
    param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, ephochs=epochs)
 
    grid = tf.keras.GridSearchCV(estimator=model,
                                 param_grid=param_grid,
                                 cv=3,
                                 verbose=2)  # include n_jobs=-1 if you are using CPU
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
 
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),
    epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=32)
 
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=32)
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1),
    predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))
 
N = np.arange(0, EPOCHS)
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(N, H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(N, H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(N, H.history["acc"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(N, H.history["val_acc"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy (Simple NN)")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(args["plot"])
 
print("[INFO] serializing network and label binarizer...")
model.save(args["model"])
f = open(args["label_bin"], "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(lb))
f.close()
```

Error:

```
C: \ WINDOWS \ system32> python D: \ keras-tutorial \ train_simple_nn.py -d codes -m output / simple_nn.model -l output / simple_nn_lb.pickle -p output / simple_nn_plot.png
2021-06-20 18: 49: 06.375743: I tensorflow / stream_executor / platform / default / dso_loader.cc: 53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
['Bcodes', 'Ccodes']
Processing image: D: \ keras-tutorial \ codes \ Bcodes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D: \ keras-tutorial \ train_simple_nn.py", line 81, in <module>
process_image (img_path)
File "D: \ keras-tutorial \ train_simple_nn.py", line 63, in process_image
img = Image.open (img_path)
File "C: \ Users \ Alex \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36 \ lib \ si te-packages \ PIL \ Image.py", line 2912, in open
fp = builtins.open (filename, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D: \\ keras-tutorial \\ codes \\ Bcodes'
```

Comment: That is a lot of code and most of it is likely unrelated to your problem. It would help to hack up a test program that removes the stuff that isn't envolved in the problem. If I have this right, `D:\\keras-tutorial\\codes\\Bcodes` is a directory, yet you are trying to open it. That's the bit of code I'd find interesting.

Comment: @tdelaney I was afraid to post a separate fragment. Suddenly there will be more errors or the whole program code will be needed to understand it.

Comment: But that's just part of debugging. Its easy to hack up a copy of a python program. Your error happens early in your code. You could just delete everything that hasn't run at the point of the error. You have command line parameters... how about an example that has hard coded vaiues? Since its a problem with opening a file, why even have `Image.open` (or any of its imports). A vanilla `open` may have the same problem, giving you great hints on what's wrong. Narrowing the problem leads to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't gone deep enough into your directory structure. Hacking your code up a bit

```
images_dir = "D:\keras-tutorial\codes"
images_list = os.listdir(images_dir)
print(images_list)
```

outputs

```
['Bcodes', 'Ccodes']
```

the subdirectories containing the images you want. You try `image.open` on these directories, not the files in these directories. If you want to process all files in the subdirectories you could use a glob pattern `D:\keras-tutorial\codes\*\*`.

```
from glob import glob
import os
images_dir = "D:\\keras-tutorial\\codes"
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    images_list = glob(os.path.join(images_dir, "*", "*"))
    print(images_list)
 
    for img_path in images_list:
        process_image(img_path)
```

If these files all share a common file extension such as ".img", you could make this code a bit safer by doing `glob(os.path.join(images_dir, "*", "*.img")` instead.

it would also be a good idea to wrap the image processing in an exception handler that has some sort of policy for files that don't process correctly.